# BeginReceiveFrom() is null?

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine

I have been tring to set up a UDP client/server in windows .net sockets.
In the client script below I am able to send a message to the server when the client "connects", but I get a null reference when I try to call the BeginToReceeve() function.

I am confused as to why I can send a message (using the server endpoint of course), but not receive because of a null error. I am new to sockets and am wondering why this is not working?

The server is a running in a windows c# application, and the client is running in a c# script in Unity3D.

```
private EndPoint epServer;
private Socket clientSocket;
private byte[] myBuffer = new byte[1024];

private void ConnectToServer ( ) {  
    clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    IPEndPoint server = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 61456);//Connect to the Local server 
    epServer = (EndPoint)server; //Access the server

    WritePacketAndSend("Hello Server");//This creates the packet and uses the BeginToSend() function to send the string to the server

    try{
         clientSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(myBuffer, 0, myBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epServer, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), epServer);//<<< Null reference here not sure why...
    } catch(Exception ex) {
         print(ex.Message); //Keep getting: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
    }
}

private void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult ar){

   print("Entered ReceiveData");//The code never enters here

  try{                              
       IPEndPoint server = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1", 61456);
       epServer = (EndPoint)server;
       clientSocket.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref epServer);

       clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);     

       print(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myBuffer));

       clientSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(myBuffer, 0, myBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epServer, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), epServer, 

      } catch (Exception ex){
          print("Receive Data: " + ex.Message); 
      }
   }
```

Comment: where´s the code for ReceiveData?

Comment: Just added the new code.